# Does heroku blocked connect to external databases? (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

i had running my app on heroku for almost a year without any problem, my app update a postgres database on one external server and read from it, suddenly my app stopped writing and reading to/from my database apparently at the end of February, what i found in logs is that heroku is trying to connect to heroku postgres servers instead of my external database:

```
2022-04-16T18:32:21.042608+00:00 app[web.1]:   original: error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "52.50.8.208", user "username", database "database", SSL off
```

The ip 52.50.8.208 is not mine, that ip is changing every xx time, so that is why i think is from the heroku postgres service

heroku is ignoring my config var "DATABASE_URL" where i have: `postgres://username:password@myserverip:port/database` but heroku is trying to connect to their heroku postgres servers instead of my server ip, heroku is trying to connect with the username, password, port and database on my config var but its ignoring my server ip...

Does anyone knows if there was a change or why is ignoring my server ip on my config vars?

Comment: 'heroku is ignoring my config var "DATABASE_URL"… heroku is trying to connect to their heroku postgres servers'—it isn't Heroku's job to use `DATABASE_URL`. _Your code_ needs to use that variable. If it doesn't, that's not Heroku's fault.

Comment: Now, Heroku might have _changed_ the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable. That's the variable its Heroku Postgres service uses. Does that variable still have the value you set it to, or do you see another value there?

Comment: Hello Chris, I know that my code needs to use that variable, however, as my question says, my app was working without any problem for almost one year, I haven't made any changes to my code in all that time.
The DATABASE_URL environment variable still have my own settings but heroku only grabs the username, port, database and password ignoring the ip

Comment: The host mentioned in the error message is the host ip address of the app server (as perceived by the database server), it is not the host ip address of the database server.  So that message is not an indication they have changed who the are connecting to.

Comment: hi @jjanes maybe is not a indication but every ip that shows the log on the connection is from aws so thats why i suppose that maybe heroku is trying to connect to they service instead grabbing the env host

Comment: Again, _Heroku_ doesn't "grab" anything. That is what _your code_ needs to do. Please [edit] your question and show the code where you use that variable.